# How to create a set of dropdowns where the list reduces as you select?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

I have a HTML form like this:

[image: image 1]

All of the dropdowns contain the same list: `Option 1, Option 2, Option 3` and the user needs to select a value for each key. This works as expected with no worries:

[image]

However, I want to enhance as it. Both the `Keys` and `Options List` can become relatively large (say 20). There is expected to be a one-to-one mapping and you can't select a value in two places. But when the list is large, it becomes easy to make a mistake and select the same value in two places. We do some client-side validation to check for duplicates but I would prefer a user experience that works by ***removing the selected option from other dropdowns such that it cannot be selected again***. Like this:

[image]

How can I go about this?

**FINAL SOLUTION**

I initially selected the Knockout solution but on second thought, I preferred Rick Hitchcock's plain JQuery solution because I can easily plug it in anywhere without any additional setup. Here's how I modified Rick's solution to be more reusable:

```
    function reducingDropdowns(dropDownSelector){
        var $dropdowns = $(dropDownSelector);
        $dropdowns.change(function() {
            // First enable all options.
            $dropdowns.find('option').prop('disabled', false);

            // Then for each dropdown, get its current value and
            // disable that option in other dropdowns.
            $dropdowns.each(function() {
                var $currDropdown= $(this);
                var currDropdownValue= $currDropdown.val();
                if(currDropdownValue !== ''){
                    var $otherDropdowns = $dropdowns.not($currDropdown);
                    $otherDropdowns.find('option').each(function() { 
                        var $option = $(this);
                        var optionIsAlreadySelected = $option.val() === currDropdownValue;
                        if(optionIsAlreadySelected)
                            $option.prop('disabled', true);
                    }); 
                }
            });
        });     
    }
```

now you can just give all your related dropdowns a common class and call something like this anywhere you need it:

```
reducingDropdowns('.myDropdownClass');
```

Thank you all for the help.

*PS: I also realized that for my application, I preferred to disable the options that were already used instead of removing them from the list completely.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can hide the used options like this:

```
$('select').change(function() {
  $('option').show();

  $('select').each(function() {
    var val= $(this).val();
    $(this).siblings('select')
      .find('option')
      .filter(function() {
        return $(this).val() === val && $(this).val() !== '';
      })
      .hide();
  });

});
```

**[Working Fiddle #1](http://jsfiddle.net/kzhd0mgd/)**

---

An alternative to removing the items is to disable them:

```
$('select').change(function() {
  $('option').prop('disabled', false);

  $('select').each(function() {
    var val= $(this).val();
    $(this).siblings('select')
      .find('option')
      .filter(function() {
        return $(this).val() === val && $(this).val() !== '';
      })
      .prop('disabled', true);
  });

});
```

[**Working Fiddle #2**](http://jsfiddle.net/pfacg1Lu/)

Comment: These are really good solutions. I especially like #2 where you just disable the selected options. I ended up going with the Knockout solution from David Sherret because my `select` options are already being served from Knockout and so it blended nicely. However, I really like this. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a very simple way of doing it and this can be made more efficient, but here's the basic idea:

**Html**

```
<select data-bind="value: value1, options: options1, optionsCaption: ''"></select>
<select data-bind="value: value2, options: options2, optionsCaption: ''"></select>
<select data-bind="value: value3, options: options3, optionsCaption: ''"></select>
```

**View Model**

```
var self = this;

this.options = ko.observableArray(['Option 1', 'Option 2', 'Option 3']);

this.value1 = ko.observable();
this.value2 = ko.observable();
this.value3 = ko.observable();

this.options1 = ko.computed(function() {
    return ko.utils.arrayFilter(this.options(), function(f) {
        return f != self.value2() && f != self.value3();
    });
}, this);

this.options2 = ko.computed(function() {
    return ko.utils.arrayFilter(this.options(), function(f) {
        return f != self.value1() && f != self.value3();
    });
}, this);

this.options3 = ko.computed(function() {
    return ko.utils.arrayFilter(this.options(), function(f) {
        return f != self.value1() && f != self.value2();
    });
}, this);
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jeyoyfdo/1/)

Comment: Nice solution. I never use Knockout, always Angular. I like to see the differences and similarities.

Comment: Thanks a lot you solved my problem. This got me started on the right path and I was able to make it more dynamic instead of expecting only 3 options.

Answer (score 1):

There is even a cleaner and easier way of doing this: http://jsfiddle.net/ejs1d3zb/5/

```
$(function () {

    $('select').change(function (){
    var val = $(this).val();
    $('select option[value='+val+']').not(this.children).remove(); 

    });
});
```

Comment: @EliasSoares What does not work? This is not constructive criticism. The fiddle works and does what OP wants. Yeah sure it's not perfect, but it is a nudge in the right direction.

Comment: I know, I did not have the time to finetune my answer. As I said it is not perfect, but with some modifications OP should get what he wants.

Comment: Right, but dont say that my comment isn't constructive... i'm just saying that it dont works. :)

Comment: @EliasSoares Haha, well depends on how you look at it. Is the glass half full or half empty :)...

Comment: Of course... but, put a real user to use it, and you will see that the glass is all empty.

Comment: This works only once but doesnt work again. When you unselect an option, it should show up in other dropdowns as available. So, this doesn't quite work. Thanks for trying.

Answer (score -1):

There is an OnChange event should have some kind of taken and available list and check against each for each comobbox